# Как при помощи Stream API получить массив String?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, приведение-типов

Имеется следующий метод:

```
public static List<String> getMessageOfBindingResult(BindingResult result) {
    return result.getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(fe -> String.format("[%s] %s", fe.getField(), fe.getDefaultMessage()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Появилась необходимость возвращать массив `String[]` вместо списка `List<String>`. В Stream API есть терминальная операция `toArray()`, но она возвращает массив Object. Пока что я сделал вот так:

```
public static String[] getMessagesOfBindingResult(BindingResult result) {
        List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
        String[] messages = new String[errors.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); i++) {
            messages[i] = String.format("[%s] %s", errors.get(i).getField(), errors.get(i).getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

Но мне кажется, что нужный массив можно получить проще, без создания кучи промежуточных списков.

Есть ли какая-то возможность получить именно массив `String[]` при помощи Stream API?

Comment: Это подойдет? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23079174/10498061

Comment: @Deepstack спасибо, да, это оно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Stream APi то предложу так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("String1");
    list.add("String2");
    list.add("String3");
    list.add("String4");

    String[] result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String string : result) {
      System.out.println(string);
    }
  }
```

а если нет то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("String1");
    list.add("String2");
    list.add("String3");
    list.add("String4");

    String[] result = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String string : result) {
      System.out.println(string);
    }
  }
```

Идея у обоих одна и таже использовать [toArray](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-list-toarray-method#:%7E:text=%E2%86%92%20%E2%86%90%20prev-,Java%20List%20toArray()%20Method,that%20of%20the%20specified%20array.)

В вашем случае это будет так

```
public static String[] getMessageOfBindingResult(BindingResult result) {
    return result.getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(fe -> String.format("[%s] %s", fe.getField(), fe.getDefaultMessage()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: Почему сразу не инициализировать массив размером листа?

Comment: Хороший вопрос задайте его

Comment: Я про ваш ответ, можно ли написать не так `toArray(new String[0]);` а допустим так `toArray(new String[list.size()]);`?

Comment: Если хотите, могу задать вопрос на стак оверфлоу, стало просто интересно, как именно этот аспект работает)

Comment: Ну ваш вопрос решается простой проверкой

Comment: @ThePrettyFace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size/29444594#29444594 почему new String[0]

Comment: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать, например, так:

```
String[] strings = IntStream
    .range(5, 100)
    .boxed()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Сделать я взял стрим от `Integer` просто как пример. Далее мы преобразуем все в строку и последней строчкой говорим, что нам нужен именно массив.